# Multiple Notification on iOS

Tags: parse-platform

The application sends multiple notifications for every new item, how can I get only one?
[Here multiple notifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdoBe.jpg)

Comment: Ask the vendor of the application.  We don't provide application support.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the notification at that time you have to save UserInfo to identify the particular notification.

**Swift 2.0:**

```
let dict:NSDictionary = ["ID" : notifiUserInfoId]
        localNotification.userInfo = dict as! [String : String]
```

In above code you have to set specific value for "ID" key. and for getting one use the following code

**Swift 2.0:**

```
    var arrNotification = NSArray()

 arrNotification = UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduledLocalNotifications!

            for notify in arrNotification
            {
                let notification = notify as! UILocalNotification
                if let info = notification.userInfo as? [String: String]
                {
                    if info["ID"] == lblCurrentOpenEventIdOnDay.text
                    {
                        //get your notification here
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Hope this will Help you!!!

Comment: Thanks for the info! But I'm using this for auto notification: https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/simple-parse-push-service/
Any method?